# What is the difference between speaking a language fluently, vs being fluent in the language?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I understand that fluent is an adjective and fluently is an adverb. I would like to know if these terms illustrate a difference in proficiency. For example, is it correct to assume that when someone says:

"He/she speaks a language fluently" implies he/she speaks it effectively enough to get by.

and

"He/she is fluent in the language" implies he/she speaks it flowingly and accurately with a native like proficiency.

Comment: It is the same difference as we see in  **being hungry** and **eating hungrily**

Comment: Yes, but how "hungry" is the question. There are different degrees of "hunger".

Comment: There is no difference in degree of fluency between the adjectival and adverbial expressions.  And your understanding of the meaning is wrong. Fluent  and fluently both mean more than "passable".

Comment: Someone who is fluent can speak the language with great facility. Someone who is speaking fluently is speaking the language with great facility.

Comment: They are equal, and "flowingly and accurately" apply to both. But not a *native-like proficiency*, which is a higher level (short of poetry). Fluent-but-not-native could include a strong accent, bookish formality, missing occasional idioms, and misunderstanding a speaker where a native would not. It shows up in writing even more than speech, and suggests not working as an interpreter into your second language.

Comment: "speaks a language fluently" emphasises speaking, "is fluent in a language" suggests proficiency more generally, even if "fluent" generally implies speech. No difference in level of proficiency, just a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: I've seen people make the claim that they speak a language fluently yet they speak it passably. So, I don't know, people might not being using these words correctly.

Comment: @Tim A person speaking a language fluently may be actively doing so or asleep at a given moment. The two interpretations are not as readily available for a person eating hungrily.

Comment: Strictly speaking, someone who relied on signing, even if able to write a foreign fluently,  could not be said to 'speak' it fluently.  But they could be said to communicate fluently in the language.

Comment: To clarify, fluency is distinct from native proficiency (= mother tongue). Not just opinion. Fluent speaking matches speaking fluently. Both mean complete comfort in a conversation, as non-French royalty learned French and conversed comfortably. But ask the French if visitors met native French demands.

Answer (score 3):

**Basically they mean the same thing.** There is no difference in the level of proficiency implied.

"Fluent" means being able to speak the language "easily and accurately". It means they can understand and make themselves understood in all normal situations. That's (in both cases) "with a native-like proficiency" and better than "effectively enough to get by".

Comment: There have been people who made the claim that they speak a language fluently, yet in reality they speak it passably. So people might not be using the right words.

Comment: @jeljel Not using the right words, or exaggerating their ability. However "fluent" doesn't mean "never makes a grammar mistake" or "sounds exactly like a native speaker".

Comment: @jeljel, however some people may mislabel their own level of facility with the English language, the accepted standard meanings of “He is fluent” and “He speaks fluently” are identical.